# A proof of the dimension theorem in Linear Algebra by Takeshi Saito

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

I am reading "Linear Algebra" written by Takeshi Saito.
I like the following proof of the dimension theorem.

> **Are there any other books whose proof of this theorem looks like Saito's proof?**

Saito's proof of the dimension theorem is like the following:

> Let $V$ be a $K$ vector space. If both $x_1, \cdots, x_m$ and $y_1, \cdots, y_n$ are bases of $V$, then $m = n$.

Saito's proof:

Let $V$ be a $K$ vector space.
Let $x_1, \cdots, x_m$ be a basis of $V$.
Let $y_1, \cdots, y_n$ be a basis of $V$.
Let $V_0 := \{0\}$ and $V_i := K x_1 + \cdots K x_i$ for $i \in \{1, \dots, m\}$.
Let $W_0 := \{0\}$ and $W_j := K y_1 + \cdots + K y_j$ for $j \in \{1, \dots, n\}$.

Consider the following sequence:
$V_{i-1} = V_{i-1} + W_0 \subset V_{i-1} + W_1 \subset \cdots \subset V_{i-1} + W_n = V$.

$x_i \notin V_{i-1} = V_{i-1} + W_0$ and $x_i \in V = V_{i-1} + W_n$.

So, we can define $f : \{1, \cdots, m\} \to \{1, \cdots, n\}$ as follows:
$f : i \mapsto \min\{j | x_i \in V_{i-1} + W_j\}$

Consider the following sequence:
$W_{j-1} = V_0 + W_{j-1} \subset V_1 + W_{j-1} \subset \cdots \subset V_m + W_{j-1} = V$.

$y_j \notin W_{j-1} = V_0 + W_{j-1}$ and $y_j \in V = V_m + W_{j-1}$.

So, we can define $g : \{1, \cdots, n\} \to \{1, \cdots, m\}$ as follows:
$g : j \mapsto \min\{i | y_j \in V_i + W_{j-1}\}$

Let $f(i) = j$.

Then, $x_i \in V_{i-1} + W_j$ and $x_i \notin V_{i-1} + W_{j-1}$.

$x_i \in V_{i-1} + W_j$, so $V_{i-1} + W_j = V_i + W_j$.
$x_i \notin V_{i-1} + W_{j-1}$, so $V_{i-1} + W_{j-1} \subsetneqq V_i + W_{j-1}$.

$x_i \in V_{i-1} + W_j$, so we can write $x_i = a y_j + z$ for some $a \in K$ and some $z \in V_{i-1} + W_{j-1}$.

$x_i \notin V_{i-1} + W_{j-1}$, so $a \neq 0$.
$y_j = \frac{1}{a} (x_i - z) \in V_i + W_{j-1}$.
$\therefore V_i + W_{j-1} = V_i + W_j$.

$\therefore V_{i-1} + W_{j-1} \subsetneqq V_i + W_{j-1} = V_i + W_j = V_{i-1} + W_j$.

$\therefore y_j \notin V_{i-1} + W_{j-1}$.

$\therefore g(j) = i$.

So, $f(i) = j \Rightarrow g(j) = i$.

Similarly, $g(j) = i \Rightarrow f(i) = j$.

$\therefore f : \{1, \cdots, m\} \rightarrow \{1, \cdots, n\}$ is bijective.

$\therefore m = n$.

Comment: It would be nice if you added a statement of the dimension theorem to the body of your question, for reference.  For what it's worth, Friedberg Insel and Spense has a nice proof of the dimension theorem, but I think it's a bit different from this one.

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, Omnomnomnom.