# Prove that if $B_1 = \bf \{v_1, v_2,..., v_n\}$ and $B_2 = \bf \{u_1, u_2,..., u_m\}$ are bases for a vector space V then $n = m$.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

> Prove that if $B_1 = \bf \{v_1, v_2, v_3,..., v_n\}$ and $B_2 = \bf \{u_1, u_2, u_3,..., u_m\}$ are bases for a vector space V then $n = m$. [That is every basis of a vector space has the same number of vectors.]

My attempt:

We prove by contradiction.

Suppose $B_{1}, B_{2}$ are bases and $m > n$. Let's first consider the simplest case where $m = n + 1$

Consider linear combination

$$ \tag{*} c_{1}\mathbf{u_{1}} + c_{2}\mathbf{u_{2}} + \cdots + c_n\mathbf{u_n} + c_{m}\mathbf{u_{m}} = \bf O$$

We know that vectors $\bf v_{1},v_{2},\cdots,v_n$ span $V$. We also know that vectors $c_{1}\mathbf{u}_{1},c_{2}\mathbf{u}_{2},\cdots,c_{m}\mathbf{u}_{m}$ *are* in $V$.

Rewrite $c_{1}\mathbf{u_{1}},c_{2}\mathbf{u_{2}},\cdots,c_{n}\mathbf{u_{n}}$ as the linear combination of vectors $\bf v_{1},v_{2},\cdots,v_{n}$:

$$c_1\mathbf{u}_{1} = \bigr(k_{(1),(1)}\mathbf{v}_{1} + k_{(1),(2)}\mathbf{v}_{2} + \cdots + k_{(1),(n)}\mathbf{v}_{n}\bigl) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}k_{(1),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i}$$
$$c_2\mathbf{u}_{2} = \bigr(k_{(2),(1)}\mathbf{v}_{1} + k_{(2),(2)}\mathbf{v}_{2} + \cdots + k_{(2),(n)}\mathbf{v}_{n}\bigl) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}k_{(2),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$c_n\mathbf{u}_{n} = \bigr(k_{(n),(1)}\mathbf{v}_{1} + k_{(n),(2)}\mathbf{v}_{2} + \cdots + k_{(n),(n)}\mathbf{v}_{n}\bigl) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}k_{(n),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i}$$

Note that each scalar has two indices, and first index corresponds to the index of the $\bf u$ (I couldn't have thought of a better way to denote them)

Substituting linear combinations obtained above into $(*)$

$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_{(1),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{n}k_{(2),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i} + \cdots + \sum_{i=1}^{n}k_{(n),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i} + c_m\mathbf{u}_m = \bf O$$

Which can be rewritten as

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_{(j),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i} + c_{m}\mathbf{u}_{m} = \bf O$$

By applying algebra of real numbers, we have

$$\sum_{j=1}^{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}k_{(j),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i} + c_{m}\mathbf{u}_{m} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{(j),(i)}\mathbf{v}_{i} + c_{m}\mathbf{u}_{m} = \sum_{i=1}^{n}\mathbf{v_{i}}\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{(j),(i)} + c_m\mathbf{u}_m = \bf O$$

Rewriting this one more time gives

$$\tag !\mathbf{v_{1}}\bigl(k_{(1),(1)},k_{(2),(1)}+\cdots +k_{(n),(1)}\bigr)+
\mathbf{v_{2}}\bigl(k_{(1),(2)},k_{(2),(2)}+\cdots +k_{(n),(2)}\bigr) + \cdots + \mathbf{v_{n}}\bigl(k_{(1),(n)},k_{(2),(n)}+\cdots +k_{(n),(n)}\bigr) + c_m\mathbf{u}_m = \bf O
$$

---

Again, we know that vectors $\{v_{1},v_{2},\cdots,v_{n}\}$ span $V$. Any vector in $V$ can be written as linear combination of the $\bf v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_n$,
and $\bf u_m$ is in $V$.

---

Hence let

$$\mathbf{u_{m}} = b_{1}\mathbf{v_{1}} + b_{2}\mathbf{v_{1}} + \cdots + b_{n}\mathbf{v_{n}}$$

Substitute scalars into $(!)$

$$\underbrace{\mathbf{v_{1}}b_{1} + \mathbf{v_{2}}b_{2} + \cdots + \mathbf{v_{n}}b_{n}}_{= \bf{u_m}} + c_m\mathbf u_m = \bf O $$

Let $c_m = -1$

$$\tag{**}\underbrace{\mathbf{v_{1}}b_{1} + \mathbf{v_{1}}b_{1} + \cdots + \mathbf{v_{1}}b_{1}}_{= \bf{u_m}} + (-1)\mathbf u_m = \bf O$$

We supposed that vectors $\{u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_m\}$ form a basis (or in other words, they are linearly independent). But we see that linear combination $(**)$ equals to zero and we have at least one non-zero scalar. And because linear combination $(**)$ is equivalent to $(*)$, we conclude that $\{u_{1},u_{2},\cdots,u_m\}$ are linearly dependent. Which is a contradiction. Therefore, if $B_{1}$ and $B_{2}$ are bases of a vector space $V$ $\implies$ $m ≠ n+1$

---

If my reasoning above is correct, it is straightforward to generalize.

Consider case $m > n$, where $m = n + a$, $a \in \mathbb Z^{+}$ (So far we only proved the proposition for $a=1$)

We have 
$$ \tag{*} c_{1}\mathbf{u_{1}} + c_{2}\mathbf{u_{2}} + \cdots + c_n\mathbf{u_n} + c_{n+1}\mathbf{u_{n+1}} + \cdots + c_{m}\mathbf{u_{m}} = \bf O$$

Then we rewrite $c_{n+1}\mathbf{u_{n+1}} + \cdots + c_{m}\mathbf{u_{m}}$ as

$$c_{n+1}\mathbf{u_{n+1}} + \cdots + c_{m}\mathbf{u_{m}} = q\bf w$$

Where $q$ is a scalar and $\bf w$ is a vector and $q\mathbf{w} ≠ \bf O$. The rest is identical to the proof above.

The proof $n>m$ is also the same, just switch $m$ and $n$ around.

---

I suppose the proof is not elegant (and admittedly not very rigorous), but is it correct?

Comment: I haven't read through your proof yet, but one proof is given on the [wiki page for the theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimension_theorem_for_vector_spaces#cite_ref-2).  I seem to remember that there's a nice proof in Friedberg Insel and Spence as well.

Comment: Another nice proof from Saito's text [is described here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2908664/81360).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I think your proof is sufficiently rigorous.  It's certainly the plan I would have gone through myself, and I trust my "wall of algebra" would have looked pretty much the same as yours.

Two notes:

- There's nothing wrong with writing $k_{i,j}$ for a family with a two-dimensional index set.
- If you introduce it a little differently, your $m=n+1$ case is the only one you need.  Your argument is that if there is a basis set with $n$ vectors, then any subset with more than $n$ vectors must be linearly dependent.  So if you just pick any $n+1$ members of $B$ and show that they are linearly dependent, then $B$ is obviously also linearly dependent.

Long story short: congratulations!  I wish I could tell you that this is the messiest proof you will have to write in linear algebra, but I think of it as being in my top 5.

Comment: Thanks for the review! I'm glad it worked out right.